# Path containing path in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, path

I am trying to evaluate if a circle is contained within another shape (in this simple example I will use a square).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib import path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

c = Circle((0, 0), radius=3)
path_c = c.get_path()
p = path.Path([(-2, -2), (-2, 2), (2, 2), (2, -2), (-2, -2)])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = patches.PathPatch(p, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
patch2 = patches.PathPatch(path_c, facecolor='blue', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.add_patch(patch2)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()

print(p.contains_path(path_c))
```

The problem I'm having is that no matter what I input into Circle, it always make a circle at the origin with radius 1. This is only the case when I use get_path but that's the only way I can use contains.path on the circle object.

Any thoughts on how I can check if a circle is contained inside another shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of a circle [is always a unit circle](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7b96f00f29b58d6d9361a2baaf66a03bc9bb80dc/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L1434)

```
self._path = Path.unit_circle()
```

Here you want to know the path of the circle after it has been added to an axes, such that it can gain some units.

So first we need to add the circle to the axes

```
c = Circle((0, 0), radius=3)
ax.add_patch(c)
```

Then we can get the transformed path (which is transformed according to the given radius and center), and check if this transformed path is contained in another path.

```
c_path = c.get_patch_transform().transform_path(c.get_path())
print(p.contains_path(c_path))
```

This prints `False` in case of `radius=3` and `True` in case of `radius<2`

Comment: Ah very nice, thank you! How do I tag your post as the answer?